# Wordpress external DB connection error

Tags: php, wordpress, database-connection

I have an external database I am trying to have a php page inside my WP connect to. If I go to the page directly outside of wordpress I see all the content from the DB displayed correctly.
If I look at the page inside of WP I get a DB connection error. Anyone know whats going on?

DB connection.php being included through a shortcode on a WP page.

```
<?php
// set database host
define ("DB_HOST", "www.example.com");
// set database user
define ("DB_USER", "user1");
// set database password
define ("DB_PASS","password1");
// set database name
define ("DB_NAME","databasename");

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die('Could not make connection to DataBase: ' . mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
?>
```

Current output is a connection failor but again, when I look at the page in my browser outside of the WP page the connection is fine and all content is displayed.

Comment: Can you add your error

Comment: no error is being displayed or I would have? again. its just poping the die alert but no error code after.

Comment: Which bit is it failing on though, you have two dies here. One for the connection to the server and the other to the database.

Comment: When I look at the file being include by the shortcode called `episodelist.php` the db connection is sound and all content is displayed correctly. Its only when I look at the page as its being include through the shortcode on the WP page that the database connection die statement shows.

Comment: As you can see the statments are different. The first one says can not connection and the other says can not select. The one thats showing is that the DB can NOT connect.

Comment: ok when you include the file do you mean you you pull all the information into the post. So if I had a page called `hello.php` and inside there it said `hello how are you`, this is the text to be included? Because in this case this would never work as you cannot use php code in wordpress editor. So it would presumably show all the code a text or just partial bits of code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40636/discussion-between-webmaster-alex-l-and-jon-paul-h)

Comment: If u join me in the chatroom I can show u in greater detail

Comment: the WP page is executing the php code. The WP page has a shortcode that includes a page called `episodelist.php` inside `episodelist.php` is a `require_once('db.php');` inside `db.php` is the php code to called DB and its that connection thats failing but again, when I call up `episodelist.php` itself all contect is displayed meaning the connection to the DB is fine and all my code is working. The only thing I can think of is that there is already a DB connection open and I dont know if you can have more the one DB connection open at a time?

Comment: Have you checked if the other server accepts mysql remote connections?

Comment: Its my own server. I have two DB's on it one stores the episode data and the other the WP DB.

Comment: Stoner do you want to join the Chatroom and Ill show u what I am seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for external connections i use the following code in template's folder functions.php

```
$wpdbNew = new wpdb('username', 'password', 'database', 'host');
$wpdbNew->show_errors();
```

and then you can use $wpdbNew for all your queries, like werdpress' default $wpdb.

Comment: Stoner you where more then EPIC with your help to me, thank you for working in chat with me through all the problems!